# Validate email & password in HTML

Tags: html, validation

I'm trying to make a form in which the user enters an email and password and after clicking submit the page redirects to another page without saving or doing anything with email and password, but I want the form to check whether the entered value for email is valid and password field is not empty. Is it possible to do in HTML (just HTML)?

Here is what I have tried so far...

```
                        <form action="../../../redirect.html">
                    <input name="username" id="login-username" class="login-input pure-u-1 " type="text" maxlength="96" tabindex="1" aria-required="true"
                    value="" placeholder="Indtast din e-mail" title="Indtast din e-mail" autocorrect="off" spellcheck="false" autofocus>

                    <input name="password" id="login-password" class="login-input pure-u-1 " type="password" maxlength="96" tabindex="1" aria-required="true"
                    value="" placeholder="Indtast din adgangskode" title="Indtast din adgangskode" autocorrect="off" spellcheck="false" autofocus>

                    <button id="login-signing" class="pure-u-1 pure-button mbr-button-primary" type="submit" value="Submit" tabindex="1">Login</button>
                    </form>
```

Comment: I have searched around and the only thing I have found is that it's possible in HTML5 but the problem is I can't use my specific classes for the inputs if I use those methods.

Comment: Well, on the email field, change it's type from "text" to "email". That will make sure that will validate email.

Comment: The problem is that it changes the class and the look of the input field when i set it to email. Any workaround for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your input use `required`

exemple

```
Username: <input type="text" name="usrname" required>
```

[From w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/TAgs/att_input_required.asp)

Comment: Thanks, but doesn't it just checke whether it's empty or not? I want to validate the email and check that the password isn't empty.

Comment: For Email input use type="email"

Comment: The problem is that it changes the class and the look of the input field when i set it to email. Is there any workaround for this?

Comment: You can add into your cass the type email next to text type

Answer (score 0):

Try using [javascript email validation](http://www.w3resource.com/javascript/form/email-validation.php)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script>
function ValidateEmail()   
{
    if (/^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/.test(myForm.email.value))  
    {
        return (true);
    }
    alert("Invalid Email");  
    return (false);
}
</script>
    <form name=myForm action='demo_form.asp' onsubmit='return ValidateEmail();'>
    <input type='text' name='email'>
    <input type='submit'>
</form>
</html>
```